# Why does PSCommand appear to ignore calls to AddParameter?

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters

In a work project, I have a web controller passing a user id and boolean flag to a wrapper for PSCommand, as the Powershell script to be executed requires the parameters. The passing of values from the web controller to my wrapper, the execution of the Powershell script, and passing back its result values all seem to function correctly. My objection is to the functionality of passing the parameters to PSCommand.

In the code that follows, I add the script and parameters to an instance of PSCommand before assigning it to the Commands property of the PowerShell instance. It does not appear to matter whether I use this technique or utilize the AddCommand method.

This is the code I had written originally, which utilizes the methods for adding parameters, but does not pass the values correctly to the executing PowerShell script:

```
private static PowerShell CreateScriptWithParams(string scriptPath, string userId, bool prod)
    {
        var cmd = new PSCommand();
        cmd.AddScript(scriptPath);
        cmd.AddParameter("Prod", prod);
        cmd.AddParameter("DeployMode", true);
        cmd.AddParameter("DeployUser", userId);

        var ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Commands = cmd;

        return ps;
    }
```

By default, the boolean flag is initialized with a false value, and the user id is just an empty string. Using the above method, these values never change. The parameters never seem to be "received", nor are they present in $args or $PSBoundParameters.

The following is the code which, to my mind, is simply tricking AddScript into doing the work for me that the AddParameter method should do. I can guess that it works in a similar fashion to executing "powershell.exe scriptname -arg arg -arg2" does in a command host, though I'm not sure of the implementation details.

```
private static PowerShell CreateScriptInlineParams(string scriptPath, string userId, bool prod)
    {
        var argString = scriptPath;

        if (prod)
            argString += " -Prod";

        var cmd = new PSCommand();
        cmd.AddScript(string.Format("{0} -DeployMode -DeployUser {1}", argString, userId));

        var ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Commands = cmd;

        return ps;
    }
```

Why is this necessary? Am I missing some crucial details?

Comment: `AddScript` -> `AddCommand`?

Comment: Could you be more explicit? As I noted, it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use ps.AddCommand(cmd) or ps.Commands = cmd, as I have only the one execution that should be queued as a command.

Comment: Script file name is command not script. So, you should add it with `AddCommand` not with `AddScript`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Script file name is command not script. So, you should add it with AddCommand not with AddScript." from the comment by PetSerAl.